# Managed Software Center - update not updating

Tags: macos, printing, driver

I have a Brother printer (model: Brother MFC-J475DW) which works fine. However, I keep getting a pop-up from "Managed Software Center" (pictured below).

I press "Update" and it says it's "Finishing..." but it just goes back to the same screen.

Is there any way to block this window from appearing? Currently, I just keep it minimized.

[image]

Comment: Are you [amenable to opening a command line](https://github.com/munki/munki/wiki/managedsoftwareupdate) and running part of this tool with verbose logs to see what’s happening?

Answer (score 0):

Managed Software Center would only be installed if this is your work computer. A lot of organisations would have things set up so you can only install updates when you are either at your workplace, or connected to their network via VPN.